# Let $M$ a manifold and $\Sigma\subset M$ a curve. How can we choose a coordinate system s.t. $\Sigma=\{(x,y)\mid x=0\}$?

Tags: manifolds

I'm quite new with manifold. Let $M$ a manifold of dimension $2$ and let $\Sigma\subset M$ a curve (i.e. a sub-manifold of dimension $1$). They say in my lecture : We choose a coordinate system s.t. $\Sigma=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\mid x=0 \}$.

**Q1)** I'm not sure how this is possible. How can I prove that such a coordinate system exist ? Alors, as written suggest that $\Sigma\subset \mathbb R^2$, but since $M$ is not $\mathbb R^2$ a priori, it may have a mistakes, no ?

**Q2)** If indeed there is a mistakes, suppose $M=\mathbb R^2$. Then, how is it possible that $\Sigma=\{(x,y)\mid x=0\}$ since we don't know the curve a priori ?

Comment: I guess that you mean that you can choose a coordinate system such that it is locally of this form. In general this will not be true.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: Isn't what I said ? 3rd line : "They say in my lecture : We choose a coordinate system s.t. Σ={(,)∈ℝ2∣=0}". Even if it's not true in general, it should be true when $M=\mathbb R^2$, no ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your last comment. Consider $$\Sigma = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ x^2+ y^2 =1\}$$ this is submanifold of dimension 1. It is not possible to find a change of coordinates to make it globally of the form you wrote. It is just possible to pick charts such that in every chart is of that form.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: Good point (sorry, I'm quite novice in manifold). And if $\Sigma=\{h(x)\mid x\in\mathbb R^2\}$ ?

Comment: What would you assume on $h$?

Comment: Let say continuity @SeverinSchraven

Comment: I guess the thing you want to consider is $$ \Sigma = \{ (x, h(x)) \} $$ ie the graph of a continuous function. This admits a global chart of your form. And hence every submanifold is locally of this form.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Could you please tell me why $\Sigma=\{(x,h(x))\mid x\in \mathbb R^2\}$ has coordinate s.t. $\Sigma=\{(x,y)\mid x=0\}$ ? (when $h$ is continuous)

Comment: Because you can consider the map $$ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \Sigma, \ x \mapsto (x, h(x)) $$ this is a global chart. It is continuous and bijective. The inverse map is $\Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{R), \ (x,y) \mapsto x $ is continuous as well.